# Calculating words similarity score in python

Tags: python, nlp, wordnet, cosine-similarity, sentence-similarity

I'm trying to calculate books similarity by comparing the topics lists.

Need to get similarity score from the 2 lists between 0-1.

Example:

```py
book1_topics = ["god", "bible", "book", "holy", "religion", "Christian"]

book2_topics = ["god", "Christ", "idol", "Jesus"]
```

Tried using wordnet but not sure how to calculate the score.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113939/spacy-strange-similarity-between-two-sentences) discussion

Comment: what would be nice is, in your question if you told us how you are comparing them. Like what makes them similar?

Comment: To complete my previous comment:  I see now that you want to calculate similarity by topics and not by words, so maybe the discussion I suggested is not on point, my bad

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [spaCy](https://spacy.io), a Python nlp library

```py
import spacy

book1_topics = ['god', 'bible', 'book', 'holy', 'religion', 'Christian']
book2_topics = ['god', 'Christ', 'idol', 'Jesus']

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
doc1 = nlp(' '.join(book1_topics))
doc2 = nlp(' '.join(book2_topics))

print(doc1.similarity(doc2))
```

Output:

```
0.822639616995468
```

### Note

You might want to install spacy:

```
pip3 install spacy
```

and the model:

```
python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to spaCy, I would also suggest the [Jaccard similarity index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) if all you're looking for is lexical overlap/similarity.

You're going to need to [install NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/install.html).

```
from nltk.util import ngrams

def jaccard_similarity(str1, str2, n):
    str1_bigrams = list(ngrams(str1, n))
    str2_bigrams = list(ngrams(str2, n))

    intersection = len(list(set(str1_bigrams).intersection(set(str2_bigrams))))
    union = (len(set(str1_bigrams)) + len(set(str2_bigrams))) - intersection

    return float(intersection) / union
```

In the above function you can choose `n` (which refers to the "n" in n-gram) to be whatever you want. I usually use `n=2` in order to use bigram Jaccard similarity, but it's up to you.

Now to apply that to your example, I'd personally calculate the bigram Jaccard similarity for each pair of words in each list and average those values (assuming you have the `jaccard_similarity` function defined above):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> book1_topics = ["god", "bible", "book", "holy", "religion", "Christian"]
>>> book2_topics = ["god", "Christ", "idol", "Jesus"]
>>> pairs = list(product(book1_topics, book2_topics))
>>> similarities = [jaccard_similarity(str1, str2, 2) for str1, str2 in pairs]
>>> avg_similarity = sum(similarities) / len(similarities)
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)

might be a good approximation if the set of topics is not big. Otherwise I would try to look at models like Word2Vec and its successors.