# Python programming finding similar names from a list of names

Tags: python, database, nlp, data-science

I am using a dataset of company names with that may contains not identical duplicates.

The list may contains : company A but also c.o.m.p.a.n.y A or comp A

Is there any python script using NLP for example that can find similar names from a dataset.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you have to train another NLP network to preprocess data for another network) Some of the caseswhere there is something like 'c.o.m.p.a.n.y' you can just remove useless characters and leave only letters

Comment: Do you know the form of the possible duplicates?

Comment: Yes I do know the general form of duplicates but not all of them

Comment: maybe these three link help you : [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388213/find-the-similarity-metric-between-two-strings) , [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162668/calculate-similarity-between-list-of-words) , [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919407/calculating-words-similarity-score-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#vectors-similarity) to get similarities between 2 texts.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")  # make sure to use larger package!
doc1 = nlp("Coca-Cola")
doc2 = nlp("Pepsi")

doc3 = nlp("Company Coca-Cola")
doc4 = nlp("Company Pepsi-Cola")


print(doc1, "<->", doc2, doc1.similarity(doc2))
print(doc3, "<->", doc4, doc3.similarity(doc4))
```

With following similarities

```
Coca-Cola <-> Pepsi 0.6684898494102074
Company Coca-Cola <-> Company Pepsi-Cola 0.934960639746236
```